# JQuery : Iterate through all <option> elements in a multiple <select> element

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple  element as follows:

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to iterate through this multiple select list and read the values of all the options.  I have this JQuery on another page that iterates through all the selected options in a multiple select element like this:

```
$('#mySelect option:selected').each(function(){ ... });
```

How do I modify the above statement so that the .each will return all of the options one by one instead of only those that are selected?

I tried these:

```
$('#mySelect option').each(function(){ ... });    

$('#mySelect option').children().each(function(){ ... });

$('#mySelect option').children(function(){ ... });

$('#mySelect > option').each(function(){ ... });
```

but none worked.

EDIT: Sorry everyone the typo was in my first statement on here then I copy/pasted it 4x's.  In my actual code the # is there but it does not work.

UGGHHH LOL the error isn't with my JQuery but with my html select element.  I was using the name attribute instead of id.

Comment: You forgot the `#` in front of the `mySelect` id.

Comment: like this- $('#mySelect option').each(function(){//do this });

Comment: Hihi, I'm so glad you found your issue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your selector is missing a `#`:

```
$('#mySelect option').each(function(){ ... });    
   ^
```

Without the `#`, you look for `<mySelect>` elements.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you're missing the `ready function` like:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uwofet/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){ // DOM is ready

    var myOptions = [] ;

    $('#mySelect option').each(function(){
      myOptions.push( this.value );
    });

    alert(  myOptions ); // 1,2,3

});
```

Comment: You can also just do it with `.map()`: `var myOptions = $('#mySelect option').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();`

Comment: @Blender you know what, I always forget about that little diamond. Thanks

Comment: @Blender why don't you add it to your answer? It's a great tip specially for jQuery starters

Comment: Because I'm lazy and I don't really know what OP wants to do with that selector.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to this:

```
$('#mySelect option')
```

right now you have it as this:

```
$('mySelect option')
```

which is looking for an element of type `mySelect`.  The # specifies that you are matching IDs